# Centre text within responsive image

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble centring text within a responsive image. I've tried `vertical-align:middle`. It vertically centres the text, but it's next to the image, not in front of the image.

As you can see my image is responsive so I would like the text to move with the image. Thank you in advance for your help.

- http://jsfiddle.net/gEh49/

#### HTML:

```
 <div class="image">
 <img src="http://static.inqmind.co/content/2013/05/aap-mob-always-strive-and-prosper/feature.jpg" class="ri" id="hv" />
 ASAP ROCKY - Jack New City</div>
 </div>
```

#### CSS:

```
 img.ri
 {
 position: relative;
 max-width: 75%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 }

 @media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
 img.ri { max-width: 90%; }
 }
 @media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
 img.ri { max-height: 90%; }
 }

 img#hv {
 filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
 filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome & Safari 6+ */
 }

 img#hv:hover {
filter: none;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
```

}

Comment: give a jsfiddle please

Comment: Sure. http://jsfiddle.net/gEh49/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it: http://jsfiddle.net/yJ8wh/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.image {position: relative; text-align: center;}

.image span {position: absolute; line-height: 20px; display: block; top: 50%; margin-top: -10px; width: 100%; color: white;}

img.ri
 {
 position: relative;
 max-width: 75%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 }

 @media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
 img.ri { max-width: 90%; }
 }
 @media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
 img.ri { max-height: 90%; }
 }

 img#hv {
 filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
 filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome & Safari 6+ */
 }

 img#hv:hover {
filter: none;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0);}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="image">
 <img src="http://static.inqmind.co/content/2013/05/aap-mob-always-strive-and-prosper/feature.jpg" class="ri" id="hv">
 <span>ASAP ROCKY - Jack New City</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want to keep everything left aligned, here's another option: http://jsfiddle.net/DqCuA/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.image {position: relative; text-align: center;}

.image b {display: block;position: absolute;line-height: 20px;  top: 50%; margin-top: -10px; width: 100%; color: white; font-weight: normal;}

img.ri
 {
 position: relative;
 max-width: 75%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 }

 @media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
 img.ri { max-width: 90%; }
 }
 @media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
 img.ri { max-height: 90%; }
 }

 img#hv {
 filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
 filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome & Safari 6+ */
 }

 img#hv:hover {
filter: none;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0);}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<span class="image">
 <img src="http://static.inqmind.co/content/2013/05/aap-mob-always-strive-and-prosper/feature.jpg" class="ri" id="hv">
 <b>ASAP ROCKY - Jack New City</b>
</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In retrospect this is exactly what I want! Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

You can center elements via CSS (if they haven't been taken out of the flow via `float` or `absolute` positioning) by setting an equal `margin` at the left and the right side of it.

```
margin-left: 50%;
margin-right: 50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

i have added

```
<span id="imgtxt">ASAP ROCKY - Jack New City</span>
```

and its css :

```
#imgtxt{
    z-index:10;
    position:absolute;
    color:white;
    left:20%;
    top:35%;
}
```

you can check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gEh49/1/) also

Comment: Hello guys, this was the problem I was having, making both the text and image relative to the browser. And making the text responsive with the browser, like how the image is.